# TYPO3 CMS 8.7.13 Install Tool Upgrade Wizard: Error when doing "Execute database migrations on single rows"

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3, fluid

I am getting the following error page with no error details when executing the step "Execute database migrations on single rows" within the TYPO3 CMS Install Tool Upgrade Wizard. I'm in the process of upgrading from TYPO3 7.6 to 8.7

I have already set Configuration presets to Debug in the install tool.

How can I see more error details?

[image]

**[Update #1]**

I just found this under "Log" in the TYPO3 backend menu and suspect it might be the issue or related to the issue but I still don't know how to fix it???

`Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1486155150: The RecordLinkHandler expects identifier and uid as $parameter configuration. | InvalidArgumentException thrown in file /some/path/vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/LinkHandling/RecordLinkHandler.php in line 40. Requested URL: https://example.com/typo3/install.php?&install[action]=upgradeWizard&install[controller]=tool&install[context]=standalone`

**[Update #2]**

Turns out that someone else on the team here had the following in  `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php` which was overriding settings within `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`...

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['debug'] = false;
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['displayErrors'] = 0;`

Once I changed these to true, I was able to see error traces... yeah! Solved.

Comment: `config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0` enable error reporting so you can get better idea.

Comment: I uncommented the `contentObjectExceptionHandler` line in my main TS file and didn't seem to make a difference... still not getting an error trace. Do you have any thoughts on the error I listed above? Not sure what would cause it... it appears that this error gets thrown based on... `if (empty($parameters['identifier']) || empty($parameters['uid']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more details about error you need to set `debug => true` in your `Locanconfiguration.php` file. like below.

```
'BE' => [
    'debug' => true
],
```

Also add below line in your typoscript template.

```
config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0
```

Comment: Still not getting an error trace. Debug was already set to true and I uncommented the `config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0` in my main TS template... but I'm not certain if typoscript can have an effect on the Install Tool error reporting or not anyway???

Comment: See Update #2 in the original question for more details of why I was having issues.